# Strange behaviour with static fields

Tags: c#, .net, generics, static-constructor

I am trying to get a custom enum class working which should enable me to create enums with user friendly identifiers and an arbitrary associated value. so far so good:

```
public class EnumBase<T, E>
    where E : class
{
    private static readonly List<E> list = new List<E>();

    private string text;
    private T value;

    public string Text { get { return text; } }
    public T Value { get { return value; } }

    public EnumBase(string text, T value)
    {
        this.text = text;
        this.value = value;
        list.Add(this as E);
    }

    protected static IEnumerable<E> ItemList
    {
        get { return list; }
    }
}

public class Zahlungsart : EnumBase<int, Zahlungsart>
{
    public static readonly Zahlungsart Erlagsschein = new Zahlungsart("Erlagsschein", 0);
    public static readonly Zahlungsart Lastschrift = new Zahlungsart("Lastschrift", 1);

    private Zahlungsart(string text, int value) : base(text, value) { }
    public static new IEnumerable<Zahlungsart> ItemList { get { return EnumBase<int, Zahlungsart>.ItemList; } }
}
```

And now my problem:

```
Console.WriteLine(Zahlungsart.ItemList.Count());
```

The following statement gives me 0, instead of 2. The problem is due to beforefieldinit, I think. I could work around this by calling some method of the specific enum directly which would force the static fields to load, but this is not the best solution, I think.

Hint: please do not propose some kind of [UserfriendlyName()]-attribute for enum here, I already know them.

**EDIT**
Thanks, hans. I had indeed a typo in my own code, calling the wrong generic specialisation.

Now my question is, can I get rid of the redefinition of ItemList in each subclass, but it seems this is necessary to to get the static fields initialized.

Comment: When I run that exact same code, I get "2" as output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code doesn't repro the problem.  But you will get a repro if you change the property like this:

```
    public new static IEnumerable<Zahlungsart> ItemList { 
        get { return EnumBase<uint, Zahlungsart>.ItemList; }   // Note: uint instead of int
    }
```

Beware that every concrete class generated from a generic type will have its own static fields, they are *not* shared.

Comment: damn you are right, I have fiddling so much around the code that I posted one that was actually working :)

Comment: Can I get around the redefinition of ItemList in each subclass? Without it, the static ctor is not called. This means count is 0, until I access the first static member of the derived class in question.

Comment: You can't, this is fundamental behavior.  The static members have a different type, sharing isn't possible.  You need to re-think this.

Answer (score 2):

How about using "static constructor" ??

```
public class Zahlungsart : EnumBase<int, Zahlungsart>
{
    public static readonly Zahlungsart Erlagsschein;
    public static readonly Zahlungsart Lastschrift;

    static Zahlungsart()
    {
        Erlagsschein = new Zahlungsart("Erlagsschein", 0);
        Lastschrift = new Zahlungsart("Lastschrift", 1);
    }

    private Zahlungsart(string text, int value) : base(text, value) { }
    public static new IEnumerable<Zahlungsart> ItemList { get { return EnumBase<int, Zahlungsart>.ItemList; } }
}
```

Comment: The compiler already automatically generates a cctor to initialize the readonly members.  This cannot make any difference.

Comment: @Hans, it can. A static constructor will remove the "beforefieldinit" flag, causing all static fields to be executed when the type is first used. A type without a static constructor is marked as "beforefieldinit", and static fields are only guaranteed to be initialized before they are first referenced, but there's no guarantee that they are initialized before other code is executed in that type. http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/beforefieldinit.html